# User Defined Classes Ruby errors

Tags: ruby, class

In my ruby class I have to make a user defined class with many variables. SO far I've created a class relating to guitars and Ive looked over the code myself for a while and can't figure out why I am getting errors on line 52/when I try to print out the examples to test the class

```
# Guitar
# Source code in /classes/person.rb

# Guitar class with instance variables @name, @brand, @type @strings and
# method take_strings.

class Guitar

  # initialize method is called when user invokes Guitar.new.
  def initialize(the_name, the_brand, the_type, the_strings)
    @name = the_name
    @brand = the_brand
    @type = the_type
    @strings = the_strings
  end

  # Define getters.
  def name
    return @name
  end

  def brand
    return @brand
  end

  def type
    return @type

  def strings
    return @strings
  end
.
  def strings=(value)
    @strings = value
  end

  def to_s
    return "#{name}; #{brand}; #{type}; #{strings}."
  end

end


guitars = [ ]

guitars << Guitar.new("Stratocaster", "Fender", "Solid Body", 6)
guitars << Guitar.new("Les Paul", "Gibson", "Solid Body", 6)
guitars << Guitar.new("White Falcon", "Gretsch", "Semi-Hollow, 6)

# Print all guitars
guitars.each do |g|
  print g, "\n"
end
```

Comment: Closing quotes missing on Semi-Hollow `"White Falcon", "Gretsch", "Semi-Hollow, 6)`

Comment: Hopefully you use a code editor that supports syntax highlighting. As you can see above, the syntax highlighter is all messed up following that line and the colors are an immediate clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things going  on here:

- On line 26, you do not have an `end` for your `def type` method
- On line 32, you have a period in the source file; that's not going to parse, and will cause issues.
- On line 49, you've omitted a closing quote after `Semi-Hollow`